# ActiveAdmin - execute before_filter only when signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to run a `before_filter` only when a user is signed into `active_admin`. In other words, run a `before_filter` except when executing session actions (new, create, destroy).

I have the following config for `active_admin`:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
config.before_filter :my_before_filter
```

The problem is that `my_before_filter` is executed every time even when the user is trying to sign in. Adding `except: []` does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

**Note:** It seemed to work as described before I ran `bundle update`. I have the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the config. block doesnt seem to take params

My workaround was

```
config.before_filter :try_this_out
```

then

```
def try_this_out
  if admin_user_signed_in?
    logger.debug  "you are here"
  end
end
```

Not ideal and clean, but it works.

Comment: I don't want the `before_filter` to be executed when the user is signing out which, in this case, it will be. I want it to run every time except when the user is signing in and out.